# Arduino not reacting to Java program with Ardulink

Tags: java, arduino, rxtx

(Using an Arduino Uno)

I've used the simple test from the Ardulink creator himself (http://www.ardulink.org/how-to-write-an-ardulink-gui-five-minutes-tutorial/ -- found under "Step 4") although I modified the program to send power to **pin 13** (the on-board LED)

The "link" appears to be correctly setting up over the communication port, and the RX LED is blinking on the board when I run the InputTest program.

However, the LED is not blinking as it's supposed to (it works fine when I'm using `digitalWrite(13, HIGH);` from the Arduino IDE)

So... everything appears to work fine - no errors, no exceptions, no funny stuff, the Arduino just isn't reacting when I use the Arduilink program.

My Arduino program (it doesn't do anything, I tried setting the pinMode for good measure, didn't help):

```
void setup()
{
  pinMode(13, OUTPUT);
}

void loop()
{
}
```

Also, my communication port seems to be "COM4" instead of "COM19", as the tutorial suggests, but I don't assume that has anything to do with it because the serial monitor in the Arduino IDE works fine for both sending and receiving.

Like the Ardulink guy, I'm also running "RXTX-2.1-7".

Any ideas?

Comment: why do you think this should do anything? there is no code to tell it to do anything? your `loop()` function is empty!

Comment: The Java program should instruct the Arduino to do something via the Ardulink library.

Comment: Why did you mark that duplicate? My question has nothing to do with that!

Answer (score 2):

Your java Ardulink programm will not be able to communicate with Arduino unless you upload an ArdulinkProtocol programm to your Arduino.

You will find the protocol files (for example: ArdulinkProtocol.ino) in the "sketches" folder of the Ardulink project files.

You can upload the protocol programm with the standard Arduino console

Comment: So simple and yet I have to go on stackoverflow to find this answer... Thanks for being helpfull